# How to send data to server that stored in RoomDb

Tags: android, android-room

I am creating an app where data first stored in RoomDb after that stored data send to the server.I have successfully stored data in RoomDb but now how can I send that data to the server.This is what I have done so far:

**ProductDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface ProductDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void insert(CartProduct... products);

}
```

**CartProduct.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "MyProduct")
public class CartProduct {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
int id;

@ColumnInfo(name="_pid")
String _pid;

@ColumnInfo(name="name")
String name;

@ColumnInfo(name="price")
int price;

@ColumnInfo(name="bulk_price")
int bulk_price;

@ColumnInfo(name="image_url")
String image_url;

@ColumnInfo(name="qnt")
int qnt;

@ColumnInfo(name ="discount_price")
int disprice;

public CartProduct(String _pid, String name, int price, int bulk_price, String image_url, int qnt,int disprice) {
    this._pid = _pid;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.bulk_price = bulk_price;
    this.image_url = image_url;
    this.qnt = qnt;
    this.disprice = disprice;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String get_pid() {
    return _pid;
}

public void set_pid(String _pid) {
    this._pid = _pid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getBulk_price() {
    return bulk_price;
}

public void setBulk_price(int bulk_price) {
    this.bulk_price = bulk_price;
}

public String getImage_url() {
    return image_url;
}

public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
    this.image_url = image_url;
}

public int getQnt() {
    return qnt;
}

public void setQnt(int qnt) {
    this.qnt = qnt;
}

public int getDisprice() {
    return disprice;
}

public void setDisprice(int disprice) {
    this.disprice = disprice;
}
}
```

**ProductDb.java**

```
@Database(entities = {CartProduct.class},version = 2,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class ProductDb extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract ProductDao productDao();

private static ProductDb instance;

public static synchronized ProductDb getInstance(Context context){

    if(instance == null){
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),ProductDb.class,"Product_db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  ProductDb db = ProductDb.getInstance(context);
  CartProduct cartProduct = new CartProduct(model.getId(),model.getName(),Integer.parseInt(model.getPrice()),
                    Integer.parseInt(model.getDisprice()),model.getImgurl(),1,Integer.parseInt(model.getDisprice()));
  db.productDao().insert(cartProduct);
```

How can I send this room data to the server?

Comment: `.allowMainThreadQueries()` this is a terrible idea

Comment: are you able to read data from room ? are you able to make api calls ? which of these are you struggling with ? are you completely unable to do both or what are you struggling with _specifically_ ? you're going to 1) read the data back and then 2) send it to the server, not sure what you're struggling with here

Comment: `.allowMainThreadQueries()` how can I correct this.

Comment: I am able to read and write data to RoomDb but I want to send data to server which is stored in RoomDB.

Comment: you will need viewmodel and apiservice class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve specific item from MyProduct table with this query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM MyProduct WHERE id =: id")
MyProduct getItemById(int id);
```

or retrieve all items from MyProduct table:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM MyProduct")
List<MyProduct> getAllItems();
```

Once you have specific item or all items, you can call api methods to send data to server.
For example, if your retrofit instance is called `api` and in your interface you have method for sending data, you should do this:

```
api.sendItem(item);
```

Comment: It looks like you've got the basics covered for retrieving data from your Room database using the Room queries. maybe use rerofit to send to the server